# Hot liquid reverse spherification

Tags: spicy-hot, spherification

Can i uses a hot liquid such as a sauce for a meat dish, to make spheres and still maintain the heat of the sauce?

Answer (score 1):

Gelled sodium alginate melts at 150F. So, this should be possible.  Maybe spherify with cooler liquid, then heat and maintain a warm temperature with a pan floating in a sous vide bath.